In Docker, sync lock file with pinned dependencies back to local machine
I would like to install some packages which are not available for my local machine on a Linux container and run it. I am using a Dockerfile with Python installed on a Linux (bullseye) machine.
I have a pyproject.yml file with the unpinned dependencies. I am using uv as the dependency manager. This is how the initial part of the file looks like:
# Use a Python image with uv pre-installed
FROM python:3.11.9-slim-bullseye
COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:latest /uv /bin/uv

# Install the project into `/app`
WORKDIR /app

# Enable bytecode compilation
ENV UV_COMPILE_BYTECODE=1

# Copy from the cache instead of linking since it's a mounted volume
ENV UV_LINK_MODE=copy

# Install the project's dependencies
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/uv \
    --mount=type=bind,source=pyproject.toml,target=pyproject.toml \
    uv lock

This uv.lock file that gets generated with the uv lock command is what I would like to be synced locally so that I can maintain it with version control. What would be the best approach for this? Since the dependencies are not available for my machine's architecture, I can't generate it locally.
I realize this is probably an antipattern, and if others have cleaner solutions to the problem, I would be happy to hear the ideas too.

change your RUN command in dockerfile to this:
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/uv \
    --mount=type=bind,source=pyproject.toml,target=pyproject.toml \
    --mount=type=bind,source=./local-lockfile-dir/uv.lock,target=/app/uv.lock \
    uv lock


mkdir -p locked_dependencies
touch locked_dependencies/uv.lock

you can use volume mount during running your image after build as follows:
docker run -v /path/to/local-lockfile-dir/uv.lock:/app/uv.lock your-image-name




Thanks for the idea. As suggested, I created a local directory locked_dependencies and then updated the Dockerfile. While building, I get this error:
0.258 error: failed to read from file `/app/uv.lock`
0.258   Caused by: Is a directory (os error 21)
------

It seems that I can only sync a directory with a directory and a file with a file. I need a valid uv.lock file first to be able to bind it.
